# Unit testing for method which have void return type

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

As a beginner in unit testing. Every example i observe that test method compare the output
with expected value

```
 Assert(expected,actual);
```

I am not able to understand if method do not have any return type then i can't test in unit testing those method.
Means if i have to write unit test then we have a mandatory to write such a method which have a return type other than void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, there is still plenty you can test, e.g. Check that no exceptions were raised:

```
Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => MyMethod(validParametersHere));
```

You can use `ExpectedException`, `Assert.Throws` or `Assert.Catch` to test negative scenarios:

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => MyMethod(invalidParametersHere));
```

Most unit test frameworks also allow you to measure that the time a method takes is within bounds (e.g. NUnit's [TimeOutAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5)).

Also, you can use a Mocking Framework to observe how the method being tested interacts with its dependencies, e.g. with [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/):

```
var dep = new Mock<IMyDependency>();
var classBeingTested = new MyClass(dep.Object);

classBeingTested.MyMethod();

dep.Verify(x => x.MethodWhichMyClassShouldHaveCalled(), Times.Once);
dep.Verify(x => x.MethodWhichMyClassShouldNotHaveCalled(), Times.Never);
```